# How to rename SQL Server Express default instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express default instance installed. I have renamed the machine. Now I am unable to connect to the database.

When I checked I still get the old server name using

```
Select @@ServerName
```

Already tried:

```
sp_dropserver 
sp_addserver
```

but no luck.

Can somebody suggest how to deal with this?

Comment: check this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22002/how-to-change-the-instance-name-of-sql-server-express-2008

Comment: sp_dropserver and sp_addserver will only inform SQL that the machine itself has changed its name AFAIK,

1. Did you add "local" to your sp_addserver argument?
2. Have you tried simply restarting SQL Server after adding the new server name?

Comment: Got the answer on following location: [Change the SQL server instance name in 2008](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22002/how-to-change-the-instance-name-of-sql-server-express-2008)

Comment: @Shaikh Farooque, please consider adding an answer and describing the steps you have followed.